# Cadence meter for the Shimano Ultegra Flight Deck 5601?

Tags: cadence

Is there a cadence meter available for the Shimano Ultegra Flight Deck 5601?  Or is there a good alternative option for measuring cadence without changing the flight deck setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shimano Flight Deck computers use 'virtual' cadence. There are switches fitted to the shifters that tell the computer which gears you have selected. The wheel sensor tells the computer how fast you are travelling. The computer works what your cadence is from there.

Comment: Any feeling on how reliable it is?  I've noticed that the shifter switches aren't 100% accurate, particularly for the front shifter.

Comment: @keflavich I had a 6502 computer with Ultegra 6600 shifters for about 3 years and can't remember having any problems. Since upgrading to 6700 shifters I can't use the flight deck computer and I really miss the virtual cadence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any Shimano product which is used for measuring cadence with these particular drive train components, but you can find many good products that will work for this application.

Having tried [wired](http://www.cateye.com/en/products/detail/CC-RD200/) and [wireless](http://www.cateye.com/en/products/detail/CC-RD400DW/) cyclocomputers, my preference is wireless, but both types work well.

You can get [good wireless cyclocomputers](http://www.sigmasport.com/us/produkte/bikecomputer/topline_2009_wireless/bc1609_sts_cadence/?flash=1) cheaply (that one has average cadence), so why go hardwired?